# I2C not working on RPi 2 B

Tags: gpio, i2c

I'm trying to make I2C work on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B.
Output of `uname -a` for software/kernel info:

```
Linux raspberrypi2 4.1.7v7-aufs #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 16 13:19:27 CEST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I added the line `dtparam=i2c`in `/boot/config.txt` and `i2c-dev` in `/etc/modules`. The correct modules get loaded at boot, as I can see with `lsmod`.

However, I2C still doesn't work. If I run `i2cdetect -y 1` I get

```
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or `/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory
```

If I run `ls -l /dev/*i2c*` I get a "No such file or directory" error. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot after enabling the i2c modules?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I did

Comment: Have you tried enabling I2C via raspi-config?

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes.

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you running?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Raspbian 8

Comment: wheezy or jessie

Comment: @SteveRobillard Jessie.

Comment: Try removing `i2c-dev` from `/etc/modules` and reboot.  Then once it's all running, `sudo modprobe -v i2c-dev`, see if it reports any problems, then check for the nodes/try `i2cdetect` again.

Comment: Use dtparam=i2c_arm=on in /boot/config.txt

Comment: @goldilocks That didn't work (no errors reported)

Comment: @joan Didn't work

Comment: Is this your own kernel?

Comment: @joan No, it's the stock one with Raspbian.

Comment: sudo modprobe i2c_bcm2708 and sudo modprobe i2c_dev?

Comment: @joan Nothing :/

Comment: you can try this. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44894/error-in-installing-i2c-tools/45087#45087

Answer (score 5):

Initially Enable the I2C protocol feature in raspberry pi:

1. sudo raspi-config
2. Enable the I2C
3. Reboot your system
4. Connect the I2C device to its SDA and SCL pin respectively refer the pin out of raspberry pi.
5. Meanwhile also add two line in the mention path :sudo nano /etc/modules
    -- # i2c-bcm2708 
    -- i2c-dev
6. Now cross check whether the correct connection are made or not
7. Go to the terminal and type "sudo i2cdetect -y 1" it will list all the connected peripheral with raspberry pi
8. If the address of the connected device is shown then initial validation is over.
9. Further you can proceed with your program.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select

> 5 Interfacing Options

Select

> P5 I2C

Select "Yes" when asked "Would you like the ARM I2C interface to be enabled?"