# Error in installing i2c-tools

Tags: raspbian-jessie, i2c

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages (1)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie/main armhf Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.raspberrypi.org_debian_dists_jessie_ui_binary-armhf_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Kindly help me with what I should do. I am using office network.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the content of /etc/apt/sources.list and any additional files present in /etc/apt/sources.list.d?

Answer (score 0):

Update your pi.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Upgrade to the latest OS.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Make sure you also enabled i2c in your kernel.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

Then add a # on the 3rd line.

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Add i2c-dev to a new line.
Then try to install i2c tool.

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
```

Comment: Please look at the help of the editor and format your answer nicely. As it is, I don't know what is English and what is a command